# Laravel Cashier using Different Model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I need to create a subscription for a user every time the user creates a job post. In [laravel cashier docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing#creating-subscriptions), the user model is the billable instance which is connected to subscriptions table. I just need to retrieve the user and create a new subscription and it will be created in subscriptions table.

How can I subscribe a user with laravel cashier every time the user creates a job post? Do I need to create a new subscriptions like table for example a job_subscriptions or should I use the default subscriptions table (provided in laravel cashier docs)?

BTW: I'm using laravel cashier braintree

Thanks!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing#single-charges

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thanks but I need to subscribe the job post so that the user will be billed monthly or yearly and not charge once.

Comment: Then you want to use https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/billing#subscription-quantity

Comment: @ceejayoz, I forgot to mention I'm using the braintree cashier and incrementing subscription is not supported. I'll update my question.

Comment: Then I'd say you're back to single charges and a cron.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thank you for your suggestion. I'm hoping for others to answer my question (fingers crossed)